# django rest api for advance search

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

i want to create a api using django rest framework which will do some advance search, say a **list of grocery item is saved in database and user want to create a list of grocery and he enters first 2 or 3 letters and then my api will do query to get rest of the item name and will suggest to user**

I have seen the documentation of [drf haystack](http://drf-haystack.readthedocs.io/en/latest/02_autocomplete.html) but not sure whether will it fulfill my requirement. Also it does not support django LTS version 1.11 .

Can you please give me some suggestion? is django rest framework itself provide any support to create such a api which will do `such advance search` which i mentioned above? i just need some suggestion as i am new in django rest framework.

Comment: please see the answer

Answer (score 1):

if you want a search with suggestions you can use jquery autocomplete input and link it a view that generate the groceries, no need to use rest-framework for this simple task.

**html code:**

```
<script>
$(function() {
   $("#your_input_id").autocomplete({
   source: "{% url 'url_name' %}",
   minLength: 2,
});
});

</script>
```

**lets create the view:**

```
import json # or simplejson
def get_grocery(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        q = request.GET.get('term', '')
        places = Grocery.objects.filter(grocery_name__icontains=q)
        results = []
        for pl in places:
            place_json = {}
            place_json['id'] = pl.id
            place_json['label'] = pl.grocery_name
            place_json['value'] = pl.grocery_name
            results.append(place_json)
        data = json.dumps(results)
    else:
        data = 'fail'
    mimetype = 'application/json'
    return HttpResponse(data, mimetype)
```

**finaly the url:**

```
url(r'^api/get_grocery/', views.get_grocery, name='url_name'),
```

> don't forget to import the jquery

```
<!-- jQuery !-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.18/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript">
</script> <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: @thanks for your effort, but unfortunately it doesn't fulfill my requirement. i want it to be done using `django rest framework`.

Comment: ok just replace my view with rest-framework that generate a json list from grocery but the input and the jquery-autocomplete will work for you

Comment: ya, one other problem with your answer is you are doing filter using `icontains` which also do not fulfill my requirement, i asked that , from the client end, a client will request 2 or 3 letters of a grocery item name and then the api will suggest him the most possible grocery item name. `icontains` will not serve the purpose, right? what do you think , if i use elastic search for that, will it be good idea to do such search?

Comment: no, the view is just for generating the list, but the that user type 2 or three char is in jquery *minLength: 2,* so please try my code you wont lose any thing